# Reasons why TalkBack skips the child elements

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm using Android TalkBack to navigate a dictionary app. The current focused element of TalkBack is indicated by the green area.

[Current focused element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibbvy.png)

Then when I swiped right to go to the next element, TalkBack skipped all the child elements, such as **Ganymede, the speaker image**. Instead, it focused on the whole WebView, indicated by the green area.

[The next element focused by TalkBack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKPim.png)

Do you know the technical reasons behind this action, like why TalkBack will skip all the child elements?

Comment: It’s hard to answer questions without code, it’s just guesswork. But it’s probably that the blue box element is focusable. When it receives focus, its contents are used as its accessible name and announced, right? What does a double tap do when it has focus?

Answer (score 0):

If you could give me the link to the app on the Play store, I would be able to investigate. However without the app I think this is due to [Accessibility Grouping](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#content-groups):

> If your app displays several UI elements that form a natural group, such as details of a song or attributes of a message, arrange these elements within a container, which is usually a subclass of `ViewGroup`. Set the container object's [`android:screenReaderFocusable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:screenReaderFocusable) attribute to true, and each inner object's [`android:focusable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:focusable) attribute to false. This way, accessibility services can present the inner elements' content descriptions, one after the other, in a single announcement. This consolidation of related elements helps users of assistive technology discover the information on the screen more efficiently.

By way of example:

```
<!-- In response to a single user interaction, accessibility services
     announce the custom content description for the group. -->
<ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/song_data_container"
    android:screenReaderFocusable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_artist_best_song">

    <!-- Content ignored by accessibility services -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:text="@string/my_song_title" />
    <!-- Content ignored by accessibility services -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:text="@string/my_songwriter"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @Quintin Balsdon's answer, when i tried to do this i get

> Attribute screenReaderFocusable is only used in API level 28 and higher (current min is 23)

from the [Accessibility Grouping](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#content-groups) docs:

> Note: On Android 4.4 (API level 19) and lower, the android:screenReaderFocusable attribute isn't available, so set the container's android:focusable attribute instead

while this only mentions API 19 and lower, it also seems to work for higher API levels